# Entity Framework Database First SQL Views

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework

I have an application that uses straight T-SQL which I'd like to use Entity Framework with. The problem is that all the data is being pulled from views, and those views are pulling their information from multiple databases (i.e. no SCHEMABINDING allowed).

When I try to import the views into my EDMX file most of the views have a warning saying that they are inferring their primary keys and will be read-only, which I am fine with. A couple of them however error with the message:

> Error 6013: The table/view '[Database].dbo.[View]' does not have a primary key defined and no valid primary key could be inferred. This table/view has been excluded. To use the entity, you will need to review your schema, add the correct keys, and uncomment it.

These views never get into the EDMX file so I can't assign primary keys for them with VS. The data they're pulling comes from another database so I can't assign primary keys (using SCHEMABINDING) on the database side either.

Any tips on what I might be able to do to force these views into the EDMX file?

Answer (score 0):

You can open the edmx file with the XML editor and add Keys like this

```
  <Key>
    <PropertyRef Name="ColumnName1" />
    <PropertyRef Name="ColumnName2" />
  </Key>
```

the whole thing should look like:

```
<EntityType Name="ViewName">
  <Key>
    <PropertyRef Name="ColumnName1" />
    <PropertyRef Name="ColumnName2" />
  </Key>
  <Property Type="String" Name="ColumnName1" />
  <Property Type="String" Name="ColumnName2" />
  <Property Type="String" Name="ColumnName3" />
</EntityType>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I already tried that. It produced a number of errors that led me to add not only the keys but also the EntitySets, DefiningQueries and EntitySetMappings. Visual Studio still refused to acknowledge that the view was imported.